# Knockout binding not working incase of inline editing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js, observable

I was trying to create an inline editing with knockout.

- I created both 'span' and 'input' for same field.
- On click of span I hide the span and 'show' the 'input'.
- But the change in the input is not reflection on the span.

**My Html field**

```
<td>
    <span data-bind="text: name" style="display: inline;">Furious Lizard</span> 
    <input data-bind="value: name" style="display: none;" type="text">
</td>
```

**My code for inline**

```
$('td').on('click', function () {
    var spanElement = $(this).find('span');
    $(this).find('span').hide();
    $(this).find('input').show().select().on('blur', function () {
        $(this).hide();
        spanElement.show();
    });
});
```

Why isn't the binding working?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/879Pk/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the reason is that eventhough you are binding to an `observableArray`, the properties on your objects are not themselves observable, so when the property is altered other bound elements aren't notified of the change.

I have edited your sample: 
http://jsfiddle.net/879Pk/3/

There you can see that the first element in your data, instead of just being standard properties, they are observable as well:

```
{
    name: ko.observable("Well-Travelled Kitten"),
    model: ko.observable(352),
    price: 75.95
}
```

***NOTE**: I didn't modify the price since you use it below for calculations. For that to work you'd have to modify all prices to be observable, and then while computing actually call the observable (using parenthesis) in order to get the actual value.*

In order to avoid having to manually create the observables for each property, Knockout has a plugin called "**Mapping**" (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) which does exactly that, using the following syntax:

```
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
```

Now, regarding your second JSFiddle, I have just made a few corrections:
http://jsfiddle.net/879Pk/5/

When you were adding the element the properties on the new one weren't observable, and you were also missing the parenthesis when evaluating the price property.

Comment: Can you guide me how to do that? I'm new with this thing

Comment: Is there any way to map the whole JSON into observable.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my code http://jsfiddle.net/879Pk/4/  How to change the total this time?

Comment: Just updated my answer, in case you were wondering why your second attempt wasn't working. But still, go for the mapping, it's much easier and less code.

Comment: k. But in your update if we change the price using inline editing the resulting total is not correct

Comment: Correct, because when you update the value, the property instead of a number becomes a text. I changed it a bit, so that while calculating the price is parsed back to float. http://jsfiddle.net/879Pk/8/

Comment: I fixed it. It was due to absence of parseInt. Thanx a lot man :)

Comment: No prob, glad to help ;)

Comment: One more doubt is there. Why is the inline edit for a row that is generated using 'add' doesn't work?  http://jsfiddle.net/sreekeshokky/vzTh8/2/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43097/discussion-between-sreekesh-okky-and-pablo-romeo)

Answer (score 0):

you want that the data writen in the input to be visible in the span element as text?
$(this).find('span').html($(this).find('input').val());